# Unable to create xpath for dynamic elements in a web table?

Tags: selenium, xpath, web, selenium-webdriver, element

For example get the element highlighted in below Image

[image]

I have tried `//div[@class='x-grid-item-container']/table/tbody/tr[@class='x-grid-row']/td` but after `td` I'm not sure what to have to use.

Comment: How I am suppose to know without your html code ?

Comment: This text `Waiting for CS Verification` is known before? Or you want to get that only by code?

Comment: It is getting populated in a web table.

Comment: I want to get it through code

Comment: @ChandaKoratI found your question on point.Thanks

Comment: @ChandaKorat please help furthur

Comment: @NitishTyagi Try the solution below

Answer (score 0):

You can use following xpath :

```
Xpath = "[contains(text()='Waiting for CS Verification')]"
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: this is giving me all the elements present on the  present and lastpage with the same text

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming(as html is not complete) that using xpath `//div[@class='x-grid-item-container']/table/tbody/tr[@class='x-grid-row']/td`, you have reached till the required field which contain the desired **font** element. In that case, you can use the following **xpath**:

```
//div[@class='x-grid-item-container']/table/tbody/tr[@class='x-grid-row']/td/descendant::font[normalize-space(text())='Waiting for CS Verification']
```

Let me know, whether this xpath works for you.